# Background task for web socket server

Tags: python, autobahn, python-asyncio

I'd like to run a web socket server to provide an interface to a raspberry pi board. Specifically, I'd like to continuously poll a sensor, process input from a web socket with reference to a variable and then run a motor if required.

I thought I would be able to have an `__init__` method on a subclass `WebSocketServerProtocol` which did the polling sensors and running motors, and with an `onMessage()` method to handle the input from the client and return the current state of the system, however I fear I don't properly understand `WebSocketServerProtocol` and `WebSocketServerFactory`, and I don't seem to be able to have the background task persist across connections.

What's the best way to achieve what I want? Perhaps autobahn is overkill – there will only ever be one client on a connected computer, so concurrency in this sense is not a problem. I'd just like the running of motors and polling sensors not to block to ensure smooth operation.

Comment: just to clarify, the web socket needs to update the critical value used to process sensor data and adjust motors. However the sensor/motor control system needs to run continuously, and not just in response to specific requests.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is run the sensor polling and the http/motor modules on different threads.

I think you can solve your problem easily without creating unnecessary additional dependencies to autobahn.

Check Python's provided `SimpleHTTPServer` (python 2.x) or `http.server` (python 3.x) modules.

You would just need to subclass the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` class to provide a `do_POST()` or `do_GET()` method(s) that do the work (they take the place of your `onMessage()` call) as in the following outline:

```
import threading

from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from BaseHTTPServer   import BaseHTTPServer

def poll():
   ...

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    protocol_version = "HTTP/1.0"
    def do_POST(self):
        if all_ok_with_the_request:
            motor.run()
    def do_GET(self):
        self.wfile.write("status = {}".format(status))

def runServer(address, port):
   httpd = BaseHTTPServer( (address, port), MyHandler )
   httpd.serve_forever()

threading.Thread(target=poll).run()
threading.Thread(target=runServer).run()
```